# Ошибка при POST из Angular в Flask

Tags: json, angularjs, post, flask

Смысл задачи в отправке данных при помощи `Angular'a` на `Flask Back-end`. После нажатия субмит кнопки данные должны попадать в базу через фласк. 
Проблема в данной ошибке: 
`'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`

Как я понимаю, по какой-то причине, `Flask` видит `JSON` пустым / не читает его. Перепробована куча вариантов, ни один пока не помог, поэтому любые идеи приветсвуются.

`Angular & HTML`: https://jsfiddle.net/L63hdrbb/

`Flask`:

```
@app.route("/", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def getData():
if request.method == 'POST':
    json_data = request.get_json()
    conn = mysql.connect()
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    query = "INSERT INTO animals_seen ('AnimalName','Place') VALUES (%s,%s)"
    cursor.execute(query, json_data['animalInput'], json_data['placeInput'])
    conn.commit()
    return render_template('index.html')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, попробуйте `request.get_json(force=True)`. Во-вторых, судя по приведённому вами фидлу, в json_data не должно быть ключей animalInput и placeInput, должны быть name и place. В-третьих, непонятно почему у вас в атрибуте формы `ng-controller` указан PostController, а в скрипте используется DateDataController.

Comment: И ng-submit это событие формы, а не кнопки. Пример автора нерабочий вообще.